# Complicated Eloquent Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a many-to-many relationship, users and roles, which I have worked out just fine.  However, I have another table I would like to relate as well, called leads.  A user and that user's role can be assigned to a lead.

So for example, I've created a Role and let's call it 'Manager'.  Now, when I am managing my Users, I'd need to be able to assign different users to different roles which will be a many-to-many relationship (a role can have many users, a user can have many roles).  So I will assign the role of 'Manager' to User A.

Now, when I am modifying my leads, I'd like to be able to assign a `role_user` to my lead (In my example, I'd like to assign a user to that lead), but I'd first need to assign a role to that Lead (Manager), and then be able to assign a user that is of that role to that lead.

Currently, I've got a many-to-many relationship setup for users and roles, using the pivot table name `role_user`.  I've then got a many-to-many relationship setup on that pivot table, `role_user`, and `leads`, using another pivot table named `lead_role_user`.

Models + Controller - http://paste.laravel.com/D6h

My error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::roles()

It feels as though I am making this much more difficult than it should be.

Comment: Can a `lead` have more than one `user`/`role`?

Comment: Yeah, the `leads` table and the `role_user` table have a many-to-many relationship.  So User A can be the Manager of a lead and User B can be another role of Contact Person for a lead, for example.  And it's possible for multiple leads to have that same exact setup.